# Replace one branch with current branch using GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github, yaml, github-actions

I am using GitHub Actions to compile some code in my `master` branch and then I want it to push all of the files to another branch `gh-pages` so that GitHub Pages can generate a site. I can't seem to get Actions to move the content of `master` to `gh-pages`.

```
name: Build & Jekyll

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    # needs: nothing
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Git stuff
        run: |
          git config user.email "email@email.com"
          git config user.name "Name"
          git add .
          git commit -m "message"
          git push origin master:gh-pages
```

I get this error in the Actions console when I push a commit to `master` (which triggers the Actions):

```
HEAD detached at 19e90c4
nothing to commit, working tree clean
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I don't understand why because I don't get any errors if I use those same `git` commands in Terminal.

I added a line in the Actions run command under 'Git stuff' `echo 'Hello, world.' >test.txt` and it instead gave these errors:

```
[detached HEAD 5edf030] message
  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test.txt
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/iwiedenm/ultimate-jekyll'
```

**SOLUTION** (from rmunn's answer):

```
name: Build & Jekyll
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    # needs: nothing
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Git stuff
        run: |
          git config user.email "your@email.com"
          git config user.name "Jonsnow"
          git add .
          git commit -m "message"
          git remote set-url origin https://USERNAME:${{secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN}}@github.com/USERNAME/REPO.git
          git remote -v
          git checkout -b gh-pages
          git push origin HEAD:gh-pages --force
```

Don't forget that `USERNAME` is your GitHub username, `ACCESS_TOKEN` is a GitHub access token secret set in your repo's secrets with write permission on repos, and `REPO` is the repository name. You can also rename `gh-pages` if you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't gotten into the GitHub actions beta yet, so although I think this answer is correct, I can't test it.

The GitHub `checkout` action currently [leaves the repo in a detached HEAD state](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/6), so there's no `master` branch for it to push. You should be able to push `HEAD:gh-pages` instead of `master:gh-pages`.

Of course, the workflow example in your question makes no changes to the working directory, so `git add .` has nothing to add to the index, so `git commit` will not create an empty commit, and then there's nothing to push. But once you have some changes (either because your compile step is working, or because you've put in a step that does `echo 'Hello, world.' >> test.txt` -- note the double arrows so that you will be appending to the file, otherwise this test would only work once since the second time you'd be committing the same contents and Git would skip the commit), then you should find that pushing `HEAD` does what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. This seems to have solved the problem and is compatible with GitHub Actions. Although, it did take some messing around with... especially with authentication since in the Actions workflow it's not easy to type a username and password that is required for pushing. For future readers wondering, I have added my final implementation to my original question.

Comment: @TMack may you share your final action yml file for others to see. I'm trying to do same.

Comment: @Noitidart the final solution is at the bottom of the question!